# Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rjags'

Tags: r, linux, conda, jags, rjags

In one of my conda environments in terminal, I am able to successfully install the package 'rjags'. However, when I run R within that environment and run library(rjags), I get the following error:

> Loading required package: coda Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rjags': .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details: call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) error: unable to load shared object '/user-path/anaconda3/envs/r-env/lib/R/library/rjags/libs/rjags.so': /user-path/anaconda3/envs/r-env/lib/R/library/rjags/libs/rjags.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4jags7Console10setRNGnameERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEj In addition: Warning messages: 1: package 'rjags' was built under R version 3.6.3 2: package 'coda' was built under R version 3.6.3

If I install and with R, perform library(rjags) in another environment or in the base environment, everything works fine. I am wondering what this error message means and how to resolve it.

The output of `conda list "^(libstdcxx-ng|r-base|r-coda|jags|r-rjags)$"` is:

```
# packages in environment at /user-path/anaconda3/envs/r-env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
jags                      4.3.0                h26a2512_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
r-base                    3.6.1                h9bb98a2_1  
r-coda                    0.19_3            r36h6115d3f_2    conda-forge
r-rjags                   4_10              r36h0357c0b_1    conda-forge
```

Comment: Could you add some details about the env to the question? I think the output from the following would be a minimum for others to attempt to replicate the issue: `conda list "^(libcxx|r-base|r-coda|jags|r-jags)$"`

Comment: @merv Sure, I put the output above

Comment: This is linux platform? If so, mind checking this instead of my previous set: `conda list "^(libstdcxx-ng|r-base|r-coda|jags|r-rjags)$"`

Comment: @merv Yes, this is linux. I have updated the above to reflect the changes.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful and I was able to recreate the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Channel Mixing Gone Wrong

I suspect that the error is due to [mixing of Conda Forge and Anaconda packages](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels). The organizations use different build stacks and so the dynamic libraries they build can end up having different internal definitions (for details, see [this Issue on the Conda Forge repository](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge.github.io/issues/616)). For example, in this case `rjags.so` is built to look for a symbol in the libraries that it links to, but it fails to find it in the Anaconda builds. Unfortunately, it links to too many (check with `ldd rjags.so`) for me to track down which specifically is causing the issue.

However, you still have a some options to get `rjags` working, just not a precision fix. In all cases **the solution is to prioritize the *conda-forge* channel**.

### Option 1: Create a new dedicated env

If you don't actually need `rjags` in this specific env, then create a new one with the packages you will need. However, when doing so, make **conda-forge** the priority channel over **defaults**:

```
conda create -n rjags_env -c conda-forge r-rjags
conda activate rjags_env
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
```

### Option 2: Recreate env using Conda Forge

If your goal is to add `rjags` to the existing env, and you can't figure out the specific package that needs to change, you instead could recreate the env with the updated priority.

First, export the env to a YAML like

```
conda env export -n r-env --no-builds > rjags_env.yaml
```

Next, edit this file so that the channels section reads:

```
name: rjags_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
```

Finally create a new version of the env with

```
conda env create -f rjags_env.yaml -n rjags_env
```

---

### Additional notes

I also looked into using the `--update-deps` flag with `conda install`, but that forces the env to update to R v4.0.1 and breaks the `r-coda` install.

Comment: Thanks! After reading this, I was actually able to resolve this by updating all the packages to be on the conda-forge channel so there was consistency. Also- in the code block under Option 1, I believe 'channel' should be 'channels'. @merv

Comment: @merryberry great - yeah I figured there was a way to do it in place, but it just was not coming to mind. Glad you got it working!

Comment: This worked for me (Option 1) thank you @merv