# Is it advisable to not mix packages in a conda environment from different conda channels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I have been advised to [not mix `conda-forge` and `anaconda` channels in one environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202874/what-is-nb-conda-kernels-equivalent-for-python-3-9/67203074?noredirect=1#comment118788701_67203074). It causes *dynamic library issue*.

Can you please tell me :

1. What this dynamic library issue is?
2. What is the suggested way to handle an environment where packages from both the channels might be needed (for they are exclusively available in only one of the channels)

Answer (score 1):

In my previous answer, I was only cautioning that *sometimes* there can be dynamic library issues, but not necessarily saying that one will occur. Such issues are known to occur (e.g., [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62526717/570918)) because Conda packages are pre-compiled, but dynamically link to dependent libraries, rather than statically linking, and since the **anaconda** channel and the **conda-forge** channels use different build stacks, this can lead to reference to symbols that are specific to the channel's particular build of a library.

The suggested solution is to set `channel_priority: strict`, i.e.,

```bash
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```